# Routing in Golang using only stdlib

Tags: go, routes, mux

Recently i started one school project, i need to make a web forum using only standard Go library. And the main obstacle i have is i don't know how to properly make routing. For example:

```
router.HandleFunc("/threads", threadsHandler)
router.HandleFunc("/threads/", postsHandler)
```

It is okay if i have only 2 routes. But i want to be able to handle more complex routes, like:

```
"/threads/{thread_name}/posts"
```

How do i do that without using Gorilla/Mux?

Comment: Write the dispatch logic in application your code. In the handler for `/threads/`, examine the request URL path and dispatch based on that.

Comment: You can check how routing is done here https://github.com/aquasecurity/lmdrouter/blob/e942d976aa03f771fbb3711563481a30d2126d13/lmdrouter.go#L176. You can build something similar for your requirement.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using some "programming". Not all things must be done by calling into some package.

Answer (score -1):

Simply you can use HTTP package to handle this case. So this package provides HTTP client and server implementations. So I think this will help you.

```
func main() {
   http.HandleFunc("/threads/{thread_name}/posts",threadsHandler)   
   log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
 }
```

And you can go to the https://golang.org/pkg/net/http this link to further details